# State machine and asynchronous messaging, avoiding unexpected events

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, state-machine

Say that you are designing a system with two subsystems: one is a state machine `A` and the other is a functional subsystem `B`. Subsystem `B` has methods like `doAsync()`, that perform some operation and later return a completion or error event back to system `A`.

Now subsystem A can receive events from other external system, like `ModeChange` which results in changing to the proper state.

Here is the problem. Say that subsystem `A` is in state `AA` that invoked the function `doAsync()` and is waiting for the completion event. Yet, before the completion event is received, I get a `ModeChange` event that now pushes subsystem `A` to state `AB`.  However, the completion event for `doAsync()` is now received on state `AB` instead of `AA` and thus captured as an unexpected event.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Here are some possible solutions and my thoughts:

1. Implement cancel operation for every async operation in system `B`.

I would prefer not to do this since it add a lot more work. It would increase the complexity of system `B`.

2. Ignore the unexpected Events.
   I don’t like this solution because it would hide other problems.

Comment: You can remember that job has been scheduled to system `B`. When the reply arrive, you know it is not an unexpected event.

Comment: Interesting, I assume that you will have to keep some sort of vector to include all of the jobs you have requested. But who would handle these events then? I suppose that I’ll need a hierarchy of states with the higher state checking the vector when an unexpected event comes in. This state would need to have a handler for all possible events for every job.

Comment: Well, that's your design, so you know what is suitable and what's not according to the available resources. If you already have a handler for receiving the job already done, you need only to add a condition: is the request was valid once and it's overdue now. If yes - you quietly ignore the answer (maybe putting an entry in the logs for potential debugging purpose). If not - it's an unexpected event to be handled like one.

Comment: Eventually, if the amount of jobs processed by external entities is too big, you may pass the task to those external entities. It does not necessarily means cancelling the job, but just setting a flag *there is a job number 1500100900, I'm not interested anymore* in the sender routine on calculation node. If the answer is calculated sender checks if it's on the list on unwanted ones and sends it or not accordingly. Knowing the system you know the workload and you can assess how those advices are reasonable and - if not - tune them to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of passing uninterested job ID to the other system. It seems to be the best idea that would scale the most.  Other solutions seem to require replication of handlers, that would require extra work when adding more and more functionality to both systems.